# Reading values from Arduino IDE in Android Studio(java) ? There is no mistake as I can see but ıt doesn't work

Tags: java, android, arduino, android-bluetooth, esp32

Have a healthy day. As I mentioned in title, I want to read values from Arduino IDE (ESP32) . I ınstall nRF Connect mobile app because ı want to check if ı'm getting value correctly or not . I got true value.Then I write an android studio code as a beginner and from tutorials ofc. It's pairing devices and then if its name ESP32, ı wanna communicate it with arduiono but ı m getting empty array.After watching tutorials and reading stackoverflow posts ı ve decided to ask for help here. I will be glad if you help me. Thanks.

[image]

```
    import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private boolean alreadyExecuted = false;
    private boolean alreadyExecuted2=false;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    TextView myLabel;



    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void connectAndTransferDataBT(BluetoothDevice mmDevice)  throws IOException{

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b");


        try {
            tmp  = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmInputStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutputStream = tmpOut;

        byte [] mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

        assert mmInputStream != null;
        numBytes = mmInputStream.read(mmBuffer);


    };
    private void getLocationPermission()
    {
        ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> locationPermissionRequest =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts
                                .RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
                            Boolean fineLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
                            Boolean coarseLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,false);
                            if (fineLocationGranted != null && fineLocationGranted) {
                            } else if (coarseLocationGranted != null && coarseLocationGranted)
                            {
                            } else 
                            {
                            }
                        }
                );
        locationPermissionRequest.launch(new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        });
    }
    public void statusCheck() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
    }
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {

        if(!alreadyExecuted) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have to enable your GPS for using Bluetooth!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            alreadyExecuted = true;

        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myBluetoothAdapter =BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Button scanningBtn = findViewById(R.id.scanningBtn);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;
        PulsatorLayout pulsator = findViewById(R.id.pulsator);
        TextView myLabel = findViewById(R.id.myLabel);



        if(myBluetoothAdapter == null) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Is Not Available on this Device!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            if(!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
            {
                //later
            }
            else
            {
                if(myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() && !myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent ( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);


                    statusCheck();
                    try {
                        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {}

                    try {
                        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {}
                    if(!gps_enabled) {
                        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
                    }
                    getLocationPermission();

                    BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            String action = intent.getAction();
                            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
                            {
                                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                                if(!stringArrayList.contains("Device : "+device.getName())) {
                                    stringArrayList.add("Device : " + device.getName());
                                    if(!alreadyExecuted2)
                                    {if (device.getName().equals("ESP32")) {
                                        mmDevice = device;
                                        alreadyExecuted2=true;
                                    }}

                                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };



                    scanningBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //scanningBtn.setEnabled(false);
                            pulsator.start();
                            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                            if(mmDevice!=null)
                            {
                                try {
                                    connectAndTransferDataBT(mmDevice);

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);




                    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringArrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String s = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainScreenActivity.class));
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/scanningBtn"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                    android:text="SCAN" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout
                    android:id="@+id/pulsator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    app:pulse_count="4"
                    app:pulse_duration="3000"
                    app:pulse_interpolator="Accelerate"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                    app:pulse_repeat="0"
                    app:pulse_startFromScratch="false" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="530dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#FBF8F8" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout><![CDATA[






    />


]]>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

and arduino code from examples BLE_notify

```
    /*
    Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCMOYS71NIU
    Based on Neil Kolban example for IDF: https://github.com/nkolban/esp32- 
    snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLE%20Tests/SampleNotify.cpp
    Ported to Arduino ESP32 by Evandro Copercini
    updated by chegewara

    Create a BLE server that, once we receive a connection, will send periodic 
    notifications.
    The service advertises itself as: 4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b
    And has a characteristic of: beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8

    The design of creating the BLE server is:
    1. Create a BLE Server
    2. Create a BLE Service
    3. Create a BLE Characteristic on the Service
    4. Create a BLE Descriptor on the characteristic
    5. Start the service.
    6. Start advertising.

    A connect hander associated with the server starts a background task that performs 
    notification
    every couple of seconds.
    */
    #include <BLEDevice.h>
    #include <BLEServer.h>
    #include <BLEUtils.h>
    #include <BLE2902.h>

    BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
    BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic = NULL;
    bool deviceConnected = false;
    bool oldDeviceConnected = false;
    uint32_t value = 0;

    // See the following for generating UUIDs:
    // https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

    #define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
    #define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"


    class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
    }
    };



  void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Create the BLE Device
  BLEDevice::init("ESP32");

  // Create the BLE Server
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create the BLE Service
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  // Create a BLE Characteristic
  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                    );

   // https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer? 
   attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml
   // Create a BLE Descriptor
   pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

   // Start the service
   pService->start();

   // Start advertising
   BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
   pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
   pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
   pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);  // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
   BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
   Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");
   }

   void loop() {
    
    if (deviceConnected) {
        
        float temp = 25.5;
        char send[8];
        dtostrf(temp,2,1,send);
      
        pCharacteristic->setValue((uint8_t*)&send, 4);
        pCharacteristic->notify();
        value++;
        delay(1000); // bluetooth stack will go into congestion, if too many packets are 
    sent, in 6 hours test i was able to go as low as 3ms
    }
    // disconnecting
    if (!deviceConnected && oldDeviceConnected) {
        delay(500); // give the bluetooth stack the chance to get things ready
        pServer->startAdvertising(); // restart advertising
        Serial.println("start advertising");
        oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
     }
     // connecting
     if (deviceConnected && !oldDeviceConnected) {
        // do stuff here on connecting
        oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ESP32 code is Bluetooth Low Energy while your Android code is Bluetooth Classic.
You have to implement BLE in your android code
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview